# Getting a dataframe from a pandas groupby to write to parquet

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, parquet, fastparquet

I have some csv data with the following columns:

`country, region, year, month, price, volume`

I need to transform this to something like the following:

`country, region, datapoints`

Where datapoints consists of either:
`(year, month, price, volume)`
 
tuple array, OR (better)

`{
   (year, month) : {price, volume}
}`

Effectively, I'm trying to reshape the data to be a timeseries that can then be stored as parquet. For what it's worth, I'm using fastparquet to write dataframes to parquet files.

Is this possible?

Comment: just an observation, the better format of datapoints as you wrote can't work in Python, `{year, month}` is a `set` and it can't be a key in a dictionary. you can eventually do `(year, month)` which is `tuble` and can be a key.

Comment: Thanks... yeah, the keys would need to be (year, month) tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to create the column 'datapoint':

```
df['datapoint'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['year'],row['month'],
                                         row['price'],row['volume']),1)
```

or

```
df['datapoint_better'] = df.apply(lambda row: {(row['year'],row['month']):
                                                 {row['price'],row['volume']}},1)
```

As I said, you can't do `{row['year'],row['month']}` as a key in a dictionary

And then if you want to get ride of the columns:

```
df = df.drop(['year','month','price','volume'],1)
```

EDIT: ok I missed the groupby, anyway, you can create two columns first with keys and item:

```
df['key'] = df.apply(lambda row: ( row['year'], row['month']),1)
df['item'] = df.apply(lambda row: { row['price'], row['volume']},1)
```

and then you do the `groupby` with `apply` and do the `pd.Series.to_dict` with this two columns such as:

```
df_output = (df.groupby(['country','region'])
               .apply(lambda df_grouped: pd.Series(df_grouped.item.values,
                                                   index=df_grouped.key).to_dict())
               .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'datapoints'}))
```

`reset_index` and `rename` is to get the expected output

Note: I would suggest to use `tuple` as well for the item and not `set` to prevent any order issues as `set` is not ordered.

Comment: This looks like it can work. But this seems to be a row-wise operation. I need to group by country, region, and then do this for each group.

Comment: @ashic sorry I missed the groupby in the title, check my EDIT, it sould work for you

Comment: Awesome... thanks. It's the series.to_dict() that I was missing.